# How to copy a directory that includes sub directories?

Tags: php, copy

On my FTP I would like to copy a directory which includes files and sub directories. Since I do not know the name of the sub directories and don't know how many they are, I need something dynamically.

This script will copy all files from one directory to another.

```
public function copyfolder($source, $destination) { 
    //Open the specified directory
    $directory = opendir($source); 

    //Create the copy folder location
    mkdir($destination);

    //Scan through the folder one file at a time
    while(($file = readdir($directory)) != false) { 
        //Copy each individual file 
        copy($source.'/' .$file, $destination.'/'.$file); 
    } 
}
```

The problem begins when the directory includes sub directories. So the code above will treat them as files. Then I want the script to be smart enough to understand that they are sub categories and try to run the same loop for them as it is going through each file of the main directory.

I don't really have a clue how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this solution is not really good because it's not portable.

You can use your system command line to copy files and it will be quicker than a php loop.

Linux : `cp -R`

Windows : `xcopy`

Ps: If you really want to use php you must do a recursive function but your script will get timeout if it take to long to copy files.

Answer (score 0):

in you php code, you can yue code as,

```
public function()
{
   ...
   $sourcedir = ...;
   $targetdir = ...;
   `cp -r $sourcedir $targetdir`;
}
```